# Limit of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mu^n_1$ and $\mu^n_2$, $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$, be a probability measures on $(X \times A, \mathfrak{B}(X) \times \mathfrak{B}(A))$ and $(X, \mathfrak{B}(X))$, respectively such that $\mu^n_1(Z \times A) = \mu^n_2(Z)$ for all $Z \in \mathfrak{B}(X)$. If $\mu^n_1 \to \mu_1$ and $\mu^n_2 \to \mu_2$ (setwise) as $n \to \infty$, do the conditional probabilities $\varphi^n$, $n = 0,1,\ldots$ that satisfy

$\mu_1^n(Z\times B) = \int_Z \varphi^n(B \mid z) \mu_2^n(dz), \qquad Z \in \mathfrak{B}(X), B \in \mathfrak{B}(A), n = 0,1,\ldots$

converge as $n \to \infty$?

Additional properties of the measure $\mu^n_1$: there exists $m \ge 0$ such that $\mu^n_1(Z \times B) \le \mu^{n+1}_1(Z \times B)$ for all $n \ge m$, $Z \in \mathfrak{B}(X)$, $B \in \mathfrak{B}(A)$.

Comment: Just to clarify, by $\mu_1^n(Z,A)$ you mean $\mu_1^n(Z \times A)$, correct?

Comment: @nullUser Yes. Editing the post